# Latex does not read my bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

The code is correct but it's like the file bib does not exist and it does exit.

This is my code

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibliographystyle{dcu}
%\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{1_ref_bib}    
%\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

I have JabRef and 1_ref_bib is in the directory. Latex should be able to see it
However it always come up with

"citation xxx undefined", And this happens for ALL citations.

The funny thing is that everything worked well few years ago in another computer. I saved and pasted all files in this new PC and now Latex runs well except for the citations. Any help?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It's not necessary to sign your questions (as [there is already a box with your username below it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures)) or to begin them with a greeting.

Comment: is your bib file `1_ref_bib.bib` ? But anyway if latex does not find the bib file it will give a warning about that, please show your log

Comment: Thank you for your comments. 1_ref_bib must be .bib because it says Bibtext database. This is in the log

Comment: this is in the log: Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations.

Answer (score 3):

If you use external bib file and bibtex, please comment out the line

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
```

This is for manually compiled bibliographies only.

Comment: Thank you. Still it doesn't work. Latex is not finding my bibliography for some reason. This in the log: Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations.